# For $E \subset \mathbb{R^n}$, is $f^p$ finite almost everywhere in $E$ if $f \in L^p(E)$?

Tags: lebesgue-measure, lp-spaces

### Q1)

I didn't learn $L^p(E)$ yet, only learned $L(E)$. In order to solve problems, however, I need to know that the following theorem is correct or not.

Let $E \subset \mathbb{R^n}$.

Then, if $f \in L^p(E)$, $f^p$ is finite almost everywhere in $E$.

---

### Q2)

My textbook said
\begin{align}f\in L(E)&\Longleftrightarrow\int_E f \quad\text{is finite}\\
f\in L^{p}(E) &\Longleftrightarrow \int_E |f|^p\lt\infty\end{align}

Why isn't absolute used in $L(E)$ while absolute is used in $L^p(E)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$L^p(E)=\{f: \int_E \vert f \vert^p <\infty \} $$

So $ f\in L^p(E) \rightarrow f^p \in L^1(E)$

Then you can prove your question 1 by contraddiction! ($f^p = \infty$ on a positive measure set then...)

About question 2, I thin you're right, there must be an absolute value!

Comment: However, my textbook gives a theorem that $f$ is finite a.e. in $E$ if $f\in{}L(E)$.

Comment: That is the point, if you can prove that $f \in L(E) $ implies $f$ finite a.e in $E$, the same proof can be used  to prove that $f \in L^p(E) $ implies $f^p$ finite a.e in $E$ one you acknowledge that $f^p \in L(E)$

Comment: Because of my poor English reading skills, I got confused. According to your second line, $f\in L^p(E) \longrightarrow f^p\in L^1(E) \longrightarrow f^p$ is finite a.e. in $E$. However, according to your thrid line, I can prove my first question is wrong by finding contradiction. Which is correct?

Comment: My third line was just an hint on how to prove it! The second line contains the true statement ;)